# Drupal 7 Commerce Paypal IPN

Tags: drupal-7, hook, paypal-ipn

How can I intercept $_POST data, as printed out from one module, in my custom module? I am using the Commerce module and Paypal to provision payments on my Drupal website.

My issue is centered around my inability to receive the Paypal IPN transaction data.

In the Drupal logs, I found the `$_POST` data I need as generated by the Commerce Checkout module. The data is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 1.00
    [invoice] => 42-1466371657
    [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
    [item_number1] => 
    [payer_id] => 69AYKSJVPCN48
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payment_date] => 14:27:58 Jun 19, 2016 PDT
    [option_selection1_1] => 1
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => utf-8
    [mc_shipping] => 0.00
    [mc_handling] => 0.00
    [first_name] => test
    [mc_fee] => 0.24
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [custom] => 
    [payer_status] => verified
    [business] => test-facilitator@email.com
    [num_cart_items] => 1
    [mc_handling1] => 0.00
    [payer_email] => test-buyer@email.com
    [verify_sign] => AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AfxmnZuHUiYodjVMGelbrZ3s3Ylv
    [mc_shipping1] => 0.00
    [tax1] => 0.00
    [option_name1_1] => Product count
    [txn_id] => 10L50068V5914254J
    [payment_type] => instant
    [last_name] => buyer
    [item_name1] => Order 42 at Mysite
    [receiver_email] => test-facilitator@email.com
    [payment_fee] => 
    [quantity1] => 1
    [receiver_id] => BGEFKZZCD22XA
    [txn_type] => cart
    [mc_gross_1] => 1.00
    [mc_currency] => GBP
    [residence_country] => GB
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [transaction_subject] => 
    [payment_gross] => 
    [auth] => AT2Z0IOHTJopgBP2XkLyQCQ8L2lhYfZUxhpmutbdOyy-ZqV7HolIN2nSv2Tl4shPAi77wEUvDTmNKAfewbCZ83Q
)
```

That output is from the following code:

```
function commerce_paypal_wps_redirect_form_validate($order, $payment_method) {
  if (!empty($payment_method['settings']['ipn_logging']) &&
    $payment_method['settings']['ipn_logging'] == 'full_ipn') {
    watchdog('commerce_paypal_wps', 'Customer returned from PayPal with the following POST data:!ipn_data', array('!ipn_data' => '<pre>' . check_plain(print_r($_POST, TRUE)) . '</pre>'), WATCHDOG_NOTICE);
  }
```

My issue is, I need access to the same data but from a custom module.

I implemented **hook_redirect_form** and **hook_form_validate** in my attempts to tap in and access the $_POST data but both were unsuccessful. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to have access to the $_POST variable, it s not best practices.
Therefore you should be able to access your data in the hook_submit_form, try to install Devel and DSM() all the variables you have access thanks to the hook definition, you might find what you are looking for.
Cheers
Denis